# Confluent Sink Connector for Azure Data Lake Gen2 fails with TimeoutException: License topic could not be created

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, azure-aks

I am working with Confluent and trying to write data from a topic to Azure Data Lake Gen2 using the sink connector. I have set up a [Connect Image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/joeplumb/azure-data-lake) which contains the [connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-data-lake-gen2-storage), deployed it in AKS using Confluent Operator, and configured it to write messages from a topic to storage, however every time I send messages to the topic, the Connecter enters a FAILED state with the following message:

```
{"name":"adls-gen2-sink",
 "connector":{"state":"FAILED","worker_id":"connectors-0.connectors.operator.svc.cluster.local:9083",
 "trace":"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: License topic could not be created\n
   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1615683285588, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1615683285689) timed out at 1615683285589 after 1 attempt(s)\n
   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.\n"},
 "tasks":[],"type":"sink"}
```

Connector config:

```
name = adls-gen2-sink
connector.class = io.confluent.connect.azure.datalake.gen2.AzureDataLakeGen2SinkConnector
tasks.max = 1
topics = clicks
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 1
format.class = io.confluent.connect.azure.storage.format.avro.AvroFormat
flush.size = 3
azure.datalake.gen2.client.id = xxx
azure.datalake.gen2.token.endpoint = https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/token
azure.datalake.gen2.account.name = xxx
azure.datalake.gen2.client.key = xxx
storage.class = io.confluent.connect.azure.datalake.gen2.storage.AzureDataLakeGen2Storage
partitioner.class = io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DailyPartitioner
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
confluent.topic = License
confluent.topic.replication.factor = 1
```

Comment: Please show your connector config

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer I have added in the initial post..

Comment: It seems you're using kubernetes, so localhost:9092 isn't going to be your correct Kafka address. Would be something like `kafka.operator.svc.cluster.local:9092`

Comment: Hmm yes good catch - I've tried updating this to the internal and external kafka address (kafka:9071 and kafka:9092) and am unfortunately getting the same error.

Comment: I don't think those short names will work, but that address is definitely the issue, and we don't know how your kubernetes cluster services are named or your networking stack is configured to really give any more information